# JSON.stringify(data) is removing certain of response

Tags: javascript

`JSON.stringify(data)` is removing certain of data

Tried the below resolution but it did not work either

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'value1'
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop2', {
  value: 'value2',
  enumerable: false
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Is there a way to stop JSON.stringify from removing extracts of data ?

Comment: If a property is not enumerable, how do you expect `JSON.stringify` to find it? `JSON.stringify` is not meant to produce a perfect replica of all possible JavaScript objects. In fact it's intentionally restricted to a subset of JavaScript to be easily transferrable.

Comment: This is by design. [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) only includes **own, enumerable** properties with string keys, not other kinds of properties (inherited, non-enumerable, properties with Symbol keys). In your example, the property being omitted is non-enumerable, so it's not included.

Comment: JSON as said is a restricted kind of Javascript Object notation, so even `JSON.stringify({x:undefined})` will do something you might not expect.

Answer (score 0):

enumerable `false` makes your property transparent to some functionalities. Try setting it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It is [explicitly documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)  that when using `JSON.stringify`:

> Only enumerable own properties are visited.

You've set the property to `enumerable: false` so it won't be included.

You can't change that behaviour of `JSON.stringify`. You could change your property definition.